# How to autocomplete file paths in Vim, just like in zsh?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, zsh

In Zsh, I can use filename completion with slashes to target a file deep in my source tree.  For instance if I type:

```
 vim s/w/t/u/f >TAB<
```

zsh replaces the pattern with:

```
 vim src/wp-contents/themes/us/functions.php
```

What I'd like is to be able to target files the same way at the Vim command line, so that typing

```
 :vi s/w/t/u/f >TAB<
```

will autocomplete to:

```
 :vi src/wp-contents/themes/us/functions.php
```

I'm trying to parse the Vim docs for wildmode, but I don't see what settings would give me this.  It's doing autocompletion for individual filenames, but not file paths.  Does Vim support this natively?  Or how can I customize the autocomplete algorithm for files?

Thanks for any advice!
-mykle-

Comment: I had answered this incorrectly based on misreading the question.  I don't know of a way to do that in Vim.  It is definitely not possible with any Vim option alone, and nothing related to `wildmode` will help.  It is possible to implement with a plugin.  I don't know if one exists.  I suddenly want this now that you brought it up, so if I can't find a plugin I'm going to write one.

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't find a plugin to do this, so I wrote one.  It's called [vim-zsh-path-completion](https://github.com/fweep/vim-zsh-path-completion).  It does what you're looking for, although via `<C-s>` rather than `<Tab>`.  You can use it with `<Tab>` for even more control over what matches, though.

It's got bugs, but for basic paths without spaces/special characters, it should work.  I think it's useful enough in its current state to be helpful.  I hope to iron out the bugs and clean up the code, but I figured I'd start soliciting feedback now.

Thanks for the idea!

**Original (wrong) answer, but with some useful information about Vim's wildmode.**

Put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest
```

That will complete to the longest unique match on `<Tab>`, including appending a `/` and descending into directories where appropriate.  If there are multiple matches, it will show a list of matches for what you've entered so far.  Then you can type more characters and `<Tab>` again to complete.

I prefer the following setting, which completes to the first unique match on `<Tab>`, and then pops up a menu if you hit `<Tab>` again, which you can navigate with the arrow keys and hit enter to select from:

```
set wildmode=list:longest,list:full
```

Check out `:help wildmenu` and `:help wildmode`.  You might also want to set `wildignore` to a list of patterns to ignore when completing.  I have mine as:

```
set wildignore=.git,*.swp,*/tmp/*
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get it working ... it's listed in my :scriptnames but I'm not getting any action with Ctrl-S .  Seems to do something with gvim, but not with plain old vim. Are there specific vim-version requirements?

Comment: It's in a state of flux, sorry.  It was mostly working when I first posted this, but it was a bit of a premature claim.  I'm working out the bugs and test-driving it right now.  Check on GitHub in a few days, and feel free to file bugs there.  I'll post one more comment here when I'm sure there's a stable release, but this isn't the right forum for status updates.

Answer (score 7):

Vim doesn't have such a feature by default. The closest buil-in feature is the wildmenu/wildmode combo but it's still very different.

[A quick look at the script section of vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?&keywords=path&show_me=20&result_ptr=160) didn't return anything but I didn't look too far: you should dig further. Maybe it's there, somewhere.

Did you try Command-T, LustyExplorer, FuzzyFinder, CtrlP or one of the many similar plugins?

I use [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) and fuzzy matching can be done on filepath or filename. When done on filepath, I can use the keysequence below to open `src/wp-contents/themes/us/functions.php` (assuming `functions.php` is the only file under `us` that starts with a `f`):

```
,f " my custom mapping for the :CtrlP command
swtuf<CR>
```

***edit***

In thinking about a possible solution I'm afraid I was a little myopic. I was focused on your exact requirements but Vim has cool tricks when it comes to opening files!

The `:e[dit]` command accepts two types of wildcards: `*` is like the `*` you would use in your shell and `**` means "any subdirectory".

So it's entirely possible to do:

```
:e s*/w*/t*/u*/f*<Tab>
```

or something like:

```
:e **/us/f<Tab>
```

or even:

```
:e **/fun<Tab>
```

Combined with the wildmode settings in Jim's answer, I think you have got a pretty powerful file navigation tool, here.

Comment: CtrlP is good stuff.  I wonder if there's an easy way to hook into it on the command-line.

Comment: I obviously agree. Do you mean "use a function from CtrlP to provide commandline completion"?

Comment: I actually deleted my answer because I'd misread the question.  But then I went and wrote a standalone plugin to do it.  See my new answer for details.  I put the `wildmode` comments in the new answer for another option.